# Posting the value from a radio button to an email

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, post

I am trying to send a value from a radio button to an email.  The idea is for an invitation so I am looking for the radio button value and also the email address.

What I have so far seems to successfully send the values and the email to my inbox, however, it only seems to send the first option regardless of what the user selects.

Also, when submitting an email and value I get the error alert 'An error occurred (2)' but the values still end up in my inbox so I am not sure why it does that.

```
<div id="invitation">
<div class="container invitation">
    <div id="successInv" class="alert alert-success invisible">
    <strong>Thank you!</strong> We'll be in touch with more details.
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span7 center">
            <form class="inline-form">
                <input id="option1" type="radio" name="type" class="span1" value="op1" checked>
                <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
                <input id="option2" type="radio" name="type" class="span1" value="op2">
                <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
                <input id="option3" type="radio" name="type" class="span1" value="op3">
                <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="invmail" class="span8" placeholder="Enter your email for an exclusive invitation" required />
                <button id="invitation" class="button button-inv">Request invitation</button>
            </form>
            <div id="err-inv" class="error centered">Please provide a valid email address.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS below:

```
 $('#invitation').click(function () {

var error = false;
    var emailCompare = /^([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([0-9a-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})$/;
    var email = $('input#nlmail').val().toLowerCase();
    if (email == "" || email == " " || !emailCompare.test(email)) {
        $('#err-inv').show(500);
        $('#err-inv').delay(4000);
        $('#err-inv').animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 500, function () {
        });
        error = true;
    }

    if (error === false) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/invitation.php',

            data: {
                email: $('#invmail').val(),
                type: $('#type').val()
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert("An error occurred (1)");
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 'OK') {
                    $('#successInv').show();
                    $('#invmail').val('')
                } else {
                    alert("An error occurred (2)");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

PHP below:

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
    if (!empty($_POST)){
  $data['success'] = true;
  $_POST  = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanEvilTags', $_POST);
  $_POST  = multiDimensionalArrayMap('cleanData', $_POST);
  $emailTo ="yourmail@yoursite.co.uk";
  $emailFrom ="contact@yoursite.co.uk";
  $emailSubject = "New invitation request";
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $type = $_POST["type"];
      if (!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email))
        $data['success'] = false;

  if($data['success'] == true){
    $message = "Email: $email - Type: $type";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";
    mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $message, $headers);
    $data['success'] = true;
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated to help me idenfity why it only sends that one, original checked, value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input class='radioval' type="radio" name="type" class="span1" value="op1">
 <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
   <input class='radioval' type="radio" name="type" class="span1" value="op2">
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
   <input class='radioval' type="radio" name="type" class="span1" value="op3">
     <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
```

And In you AJAX call, change

```
data: {
                email: $('#invmail').val(),
                type: $('.radioval').is(':checked').val()
            },
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  When I remove the id for the input fields it prevents the CSS from displaying which one has been 'checked'.  If I put the id to be 'radioval' then the labels no longer recognise the id and the same thing happens.  Everything then ends up as Option 1

Comment: A good old bit of trial and error with your direction has got it coming through in the email.  Had to use  type: $('.radioval:checked').val().  Thanks!  I still have the problem that 'An error occurred (2)' comes up as an alert everytime.  The success message is not shown so the page is failing somehow.

Comment: What I have done to hack it is  put the success code to show regardless on the else statement.  However, there must be a fundamental error in the code so I swapped alert("An error occurred (2)"); with $('#successInv').show(); but of course this is not ideal :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#successInv').show();
                    $('#invmail').val('')
                } else {
                    alert("An error occurred (2)");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Interestingly that does the same thing (And error occurred (2)) as the success: function (response) except doesn't actually send the mail.